# Executar código antes da execução da primeira activity

Tags: android

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho uma *splash* *screen* que será chamada somente se for a primeira execução da aplicação. 
Caso não seja a primeira execução gostaria de chamar outra *Activity*.

Tentei o seguinte... fazer uma `InitialActivity` do jeito abaixo:

```
public class InitialActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isFirstUse = sharedPref.getBoolean("is_first_use", true);

        if (isFirstUse)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is_first_use", false);
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class));
        } else {
            //verify mode and call correct activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que esse cara chama o `super.onCreate` e acaba criando essa *Activity*. Acontece que mostra uma tela branca antes de decidir qual *Activity* inicial eu quero ir.

Como posso solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro criei um tema:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Depois adicionei esse cara no manifesto:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode finalizar a **InitialActivity** logo após chamar a **MainActivity** fazendo assim:

```
startAcitivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Fazendo assim, sua **Activity** será encerrada antes de ser exibida, pois só será exibida quando `onStart()` for chamado, o que não acontecerá se executar `finish()` antes.

Comment: Isso não vai atrapalhar a execução do código depois do onCreate?

Comment: Não vai. O código será executado normalmente e depois do `onCreate()` o `onDestroy()` será executado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode controlar isso criando uma classe que herda da classe Application, e nela você controla uma variável que será salva nas preferências.

**Definindo sua classe de aplicativo**

Se queremos uma classe de aplicativo personalizada, começamos criando uma nova classe que estende o android.app.Application da seguinte maneira:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```

E especifique a propriedade android: name no nó  no AndroidManifest.

```
<application 
   android:name=".MyCustomApplication"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   ...>
```

Isso é tudo que você precisa para começar a usar seu aplicativo personalizado.

Comment: Olá @jose bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Sua resposta é uma boa sugestão, mas seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta, um exemplo do código já ajudaria bastante!

Comment: @Lucas Duete post editado. Mais referências

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application